# Unable to access port forwarded by ssh tunnel on public interface

Tags: linux, ssh, firewall, tcp

I used the following command:

```
ssh root@58.36.132.124 -N -R *:11222:127.0.0.1:11222
```

To forward a server running locally on port 11222, to the server with the aforementioned public IP.

However, I can't the application by calling 58.36.132.124:11222, I can only access localhost:11222 (when ssh-ed into 58.36.132.124).

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Check yo firewall? Can you nc locally to the public IP:port?

Comment: Also check selinux

Comment: I've obviously checked the firewall. Running something like python -m http.server 11222 and then accessing 58.36.132.124:11222 works just fine. And, no,  I can't access said ip:port even from the same machine

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/591963

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://superuser.com/a/591963/365431

You must set sshd server config to allow **GatewayPorts**

`ssh root@58.36.132.124 -N -R 0.0.0.0:11222:127.0.0.1:11222`

on the server, add `GatewayPorts yes`

use `ss -apln | grep 11222` to test that it is listening on `::` or `*` and not `::1`